# Django + SQLServer conexão recusada pela máquina de destino

Tags: sql-server, django

Quando tento fazer minha conexão entre o banco de dados local e o django recebo o erro

`[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Provedor TCP: Nenhuma conexão pôde ser feita porque a máquina de destino as recusou ativamente.\r\n (10061)`

minha conexão no django esta a seguinte

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'testeacom',
        'USER': 'acom',
        'PASSWORD': 'pw1234',
        'HOST': 'DESKTOP-HOBM5G3',
        'PORT': 1433,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },
    }
}
```

Ja tentei usar outras bibliotecas de sqlserver, também tentei trocar o host por 'localhost'  mas não mudou muito o resultado. Abaixo tem algumas imagens com informações do banco criado, se algúem puder me ajudar, não achei nenhum tutorial muito claro de como realizar essa conexão entre essas duas tecnologias.

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXvZq.png)

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cvj4e.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está no modo de autenticação do servidor. Analisando a imagem compartilhada, o  método de autenticação está como "Autenticação do Windows" quando deveria ser "Autenticação do SQL Server". No modo de autenticação do Windows o usuário se conecta por uma conta de usuário do Windows, o SQL Server valida o nome e a senha da conta usando o token da entidade do Windows no sistema operacional, ou seja, a identidade de usuário é confirmada pelo Windows. Já na autenticação do SQL Server, os logons são criados no SQL Server e o nome de usuário e a senha são criados usando o SQL Server e são armazenados no SQL Server. Mudando o mode de autenticação irá resolver o teu problema.